# Laravel: suddenly getting 419 CSRF Token Mismatch errors

Tags: php, laravel

I have been getting this error for the laste week on all my axios requests (except first one) on my laravel-vue app, it happens to all my api routes.

I'm attaching csrf token to all my axios requests inside bottstrap.js.

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');


if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
    console.log('CSRF token found');
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

and added the proper meta-tag to all my blade files:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My route/s are all inside api.php file, they don't have sanctum middleware enabled.

```
Route::post('/chats/test-endpoint','App\Http\Controllers\Api\ChatController@testEndpoint');
```

Api middlewares:

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

When I inspect network tab I can see X-XSRF-TOKEN is added to request headers (no X-CRSF-TOKEN though):

Request headers:

```
Cookie : XSRF-TOKEN = eyJpd...; app_session = eyJpd...

X-XSRF-TOKEN = eyJpd...
```

Response headers:

```
Set-Cookie : app_session = eyJpd...
```

The thing is, when I console log inside my vue component the content of the meta tag token, I get a different one, not sure if this is becauseI get the unencrypted value.

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
console.log('token',token);

token gbczby2kuUI1nSMs6AEMsV7tv...
```

Please help me, this never happened while I was developing my laravel apps.

Comment: There are many reasons for the 419 error, but for us, the 419 happened when a doubled cookie happened to appear, but clearing both doubled cookies and reloading solved the issue. (apparently the wrong cookie was reference, both had different values)